# How do I extract a certain portion of a string and make it clickable in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a JS string of this form:

```js
const pageContent = "He stood up and asked the teacher, "Can you elaborate the last point please? ".
```

I want to map the words to a page and represent it in a view such that the words are clickable. Is there a way to be extract portions of the string using the word index such that any punctuation marks occuring before and after any words are not clickable but the words are? For instance the word `Can` is clickable but not `"Can`?

**PS:** I cannot use the **split** function to convert the string into an array and map it as this can lead to failure in some edge cases and alters the text flow when converted back into a string. I have the indexes of all the words in a separate array with the starting and end index of each word in the string and want to use these.

Any help is highly appreciated

Comment: What do you mean by "word index"? It sounds like you already know where the words are, so I'm not sure how finding `Can` vs `"Can` is related? Could you maybe post your attempts using `split()` so we can see the specific problem? Code is always one of the most concise ways to get the subtleties of your problem across.

Comment: I'm not an expert in regex, but I think using RegEx with word boundaries (often `\b` I think) could help here.

Comment: Also, your sample string is invalid - there are three double quotation marks. But it might just be easiest to strip out the punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

Simple use two for loops and check if the word matches any of the words in the excluded words array

```js
const pageContent = 'He stood up and asked the teacher, "Can you elaborate the last point please?", Can you elaborate the last point please? '
const indexes = [
  [35, 39],
  [9, 11]
]
const excluded_words = ['"Can']
for (let i = 0, len = indexes.length; i < len; i++) {
  const word = pageContent.substring(indexes[i][0], indexes[i][1]);

  for (let i = 0, len = excluded_words.length; i < len; i++) {
    if (word.indexOf(excluded_words[i]) > -1) {
      console.log(word, " is excluded");
      break;
    }
    if (i === len - 1) {
      console.log(word, " is included")
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I don' think I was clear enough in the original question. I meant that I want to exclude punctuation marks occuring before and after any words from being clickable.